# i want to set datepicker-options min and max date under method

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

hey everyone i want to set date `datepicker-options` set max and min date but i have max and min date from method argument how can i assign here is my code

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Salary Date" uib-datepicker-popup="M/d/yyyy" ng-model="form.SalaryDate" is-open="form.opened" required="required" ng-click="popen($event,'opened')" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" datepicker-options="options" class="form-control" />

scope.Edit = function (salary) {
            var salaryDate = new Date(salary.SalaryDate);
            var s_dd = salaryDate.getDate();
            var s_mm = salaryDate.getMonth();
            var s_yy = salaryDate.getFullYear();

            var currentDate = new Date();
            var c_dd = currentDate.getDate();
            var c_mm = currentDate.getMonth();
            var c_yy = currentDate.getFullYear();

            scope.options = {
                minDate: new Date(s_yy, s_mm, s_dd),
                maxDate: new Date(c_yy, c_mm, c_dd)
            };           
        };
```

but this code is not working. it is showing all months. please help me how can i fixed this

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed issue by this way

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Salary Date" uib-datepicker-popup="M/d/yyyy" ng-model="form.SalaryDate" is-open="form.opened" required="required" ng-click="popen($event,'opened')" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" datepicker-options="{minDate: minDate, maxDate: maxDate }" class="form-control" />
```

and set the scope of `minDate` and `maxDate`